# Webdriver: Unable to enter value inside nested iframe,frameset and frame

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm developed the script using selenium with java and facing the issue as unable to enter the value in the frame.

Please assist me on this.

```html
HTML snippet:

<html>
<head>
<frameset>
<frame name ='test'...>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form>
<div>
     <iframe name ='test1'..>
 <html>
 <head>
     <frameset name='MainContainer'..>
     <frame name ='General' ..>
   <div> .....</div>
     <frame name ='GlobalOptions' ..>
   <input name="scr" type="textbox" size="9" maxLength="8"/>
    <frameset name='Container'..>
   <frame name ='Gen' ..>
   <div> .....</div>
   <frame name ='Glo' ..>
   <div> .....</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
...
</html>
```

Comment: Below is code
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("test")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("test1")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("GlobalOptions")));
driver.findElement(By.name("scr")).sendKeys("CART");

Comment: please put your code snippets to question, because in comments it looks unreadable

Answer (score 1):

You have such complex frame structure. I think it's better to use JavascriptExecutor. Try this code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByName('scr').item(0).value = 'new text';");
```

Comment: Exception thrown Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

You have to navigate to the frame first.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("test1")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("MainContainer")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("General")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("GlobalOptions")));
driver.findElement(By.name("scr")).sendKeys("CART");
```

Comment: it arent working. No such frame exception exist for the second line.

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("test1")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("General")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("GlobalOptions")));
driver.findElement(By.name("scr")).sendKeys("CART");

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to switch in frame:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ur frame name");
```

Comment: actually, first u have to switch to parent frame and than switch to child frame...after that perform sendkeys() operation.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution after spent long time. We need to switch from one frame to another frame like if i want to enter some value inside the General frame then script like driver.switchTo().frame("test").switchTo().frame("test1").switchTo().frame("General");